# Is it ok to feed these waste water pipes into a gutter channel

Tags: plumbing, drainage, gutters

I'm in the process of replacing a load of rotten decking. While I have the decking up I decided to fit a gutter channel under the outside tap. The channel is quite deep (shown) and will go against the wall under the tap so that it's flush with the decking when I put it back down.

As you can see from the photo, access to the drain (under the decking) is rather congested by the kitchen outlet and the rain gutter.
One solution is to cut the kitchen drain pipe and the rainwater downpipe and feed them into the top of the new drain channel (cut holes for them in the top of the drain channel so they protrude into the drain channel itself.

That way I have only one pipe (the outlet from the drain channel) going into the main drain and everything fits. The rain downpipe does not get much flow, but the kitchen waste pipe comes from the sink and also the dishwasher etc.

Is it ok to do this? The gutter channel looks like it would easily take that amount of water.

[image: Gutter Drain]

Comment: Depends on your locale.  Quite a few places that would be illegal.

Comment: @crip659 This is in the UK. Both of the current pipes feed into the same drain anyway, so it would seem to be ok.

Comment: If going into the main drain/sewer it should be okay if your local allows you to drain rain water in the sewer, some places don't if they have storm drains or rain drains just to go on ground.

Comment: Kitchen drain pipe? Do you mean graywater? I'd guess that it's required for that to be in a pipe, not a trough. That would be third-world stuff.

Comment: @isherwood I see, so the greywater would smell in the trough?

Comment: If that vertical pipe is tied directly into the sewer, not a storm drain, you'll be getting sewer gas coming out of it. If it's tied into the storm drain, not the sewer, most places don't allow you to put sewage into the storm drains because the storm drain lines do _not_ go to the sewage treatment plant.

Comment: And potentially overflow, creating a groundwater pollution issue.

Comment: That grey plastic channel in your pic does not look like it's intended to be installed vertically. That kind of thing is normally laid horizontally (with appropriate slope ofc).